# Implement a payment system into an android app with spring back-end

Tags: android, spring, payment

I am creating a project which consists of an android app and a spring server. Now I am having some problems with payment system integration. The problem is that for payment system implementation I should have a merchant account, and for creating one I should have my company officialy registered. But I do not want to register the company unless I am sure that my product actually works. The project's core logic is based on payment operations so I can not be sure that it works until I integrate a payment system in it.

**The project's main logic is: User A makes a service to user B and then user B sends money to user A. Project owner gets a fee for each operation. It is important to have an ability to work with bank cards (not only with digital wallets).**

Maybe there is an ability to implement such logic without company registration? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Payment processing feature cannot be simulated. But you can setup test payment gateway. Every Payment gateway provider has this feature, and they will provide test cards too. You can use them and test it in real time. If you are satisfied then you can move to their production environment.